# Codeigniter: return datetime from db formatted

Tags: datetime, codeigniter, formatting, format

I'd like to format a datetime entry stored in a SQL db in a friendly format.

I'm just returning a simple query as a row(date)...

Is there a quick/easy way to do this?

*I can post examples, if need be.*

Right now the query is in a foreach loop:

```
<?php print $row['exp_date']?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the [php date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Day of the week:

```
echo date("l", strtotime($row['exp_date'])); // monday
```

More complex sample:

```
echo date("l jS \of F Y h:i:s A", strtotime($row['exp_date'])); // Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
```